# Visual Studio Setup Project ALLUSERS=1

Tags: visual-studio, windows-installer

If I set "*InstallAllUsers*" to **false**, *ALLUSERS* will be set to **""**.

If I set "*InstallAllUsers*" to **true**, *ALLUSERS* will be **"2"**.

Both options are not what I want. How can I create a setup with Visual Studio that has *ALLUSERS* set to **1**?

Comment: I don't use Visual Studio Setup Projects, they have [too many limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2637666) and hence seem unsuitable for anything but trivial deployment projects. [Some further warnings here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47944893). It is possible to post-process an MSI to add constructs - for example to add ALLUSERS to the property table. [Here is a sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69399243/129130). There could be a trick in the VSSetup project to do the same, but I am not aware of any (anymore).

Comment: [An older answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8841415/129130).